# CUDA install issue: Invalid cross-device link

Tags: drivers, nvidia, cuda

I am trying to install CUDA on Ubuntu 18.04, on a headless server (no graphical), following official [guide](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads?target_os=Linux&target_arch=x86_64&target_distro=Ubuntu&target_version=1804&target_type=deblocal), but I face errors:

```
# remove previous
apt-get update
apt-get remove --auto-remove nvidia-cuda-toolkit 
apt-get purge nvidia-cuda-toolkit 
apt-get purge --auto-remove nvidia-cuda-toolkit 
apt-get autoremove
# install new
wget https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64/cuda-ubuntu1804.pin
sudo mv cuda-ubuntu1804.pin /etc/apt/preferences.d/cuda-repository-pin-600
wget http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/11.0.1/local_installers/cuda-repo-ubuntu1804-11-0-local_11.0.1-450.36.06-1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i cuda-repo-ubuntu1804-11-0-local_11.0.1-450.36.06-1_amd64.deb
sudo apt-key add /var/cuda-repo-ubuntu1804-11-0-local/7fa2af80.pub
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y install cuda
```

Issues at the end of the process `sudo apt-get -y install cuda`:

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-7DzKEt/135-nvidia-compute-utils-450_450.36.06-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-7DzKEt/140-nvidia-utils-450_450.36.06-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Doing `sudo apt-get -y install cuda` again:

```
 Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree
    Reading state information... Done
    cuda is already the newest version (11.0.1-1).
    You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
    The following packages have unmet dependencies:
     cuda-drivers-450 : Depends: nvidia-compute-utils-450 (>= 450.36.06) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: nvidia-utils-450 (>= 450.36.06) but it is not going to be installed
     nvidia-driver-450 : Depends: nvidia-compute-utils-450 (= 450.36.06-0ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
                         Depends: nvidia-utils-450 (= 450.36.06-0ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
                         Recommends: libnvidia-compute-450:i386 (= 450.36.06-0ubuntu1) but it is not installable
                         Recommends: libnvidia-decode-450:i386 (= 450.36.06-0ubuntu1) but it is not installable
                         Recommends: libnvidia-encode-450:i386 (= 450.36.06-0ubuntu1) but it is not installable
                         Recommends: libnvidia-ifr1-450:i386 (= 450.36.06-0ubuntu1) but it is not installable
                         Recommends: libnvidia-fbc1-450:i386 (= 450.36.06-0ubuntu1) but it is not installable
                         Recommends: libnvidia-gl-450:i386 (= 450.36.06-0ubuntu1) but it is not installable
    E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Doing `apt --fix-broken install`:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  nvidia-compute-utils-450 nvidia-utils-450
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  nvidia-compute-utils-450 nvidia-utils-450
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
313 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/489 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1570 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
Get:1 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu1804-11-0-local  nvidia-compute-utils-450 450.36.06-0ubuntu1 [123 kB]
Get:2 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu1804-11-0-local  nvidia-utils-450 450.36.06-0ubuntu1 [366 kB]
debconf: delaying package configuration, since apt-utils is not installed
(Reading database ... 77110 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../nvidia-compute-utils-450_450.36.06-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nvidia-compute-utils-450 (450.36.06-0ubuntu1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cuda-repo-ubuntu1804-11-0-local/./nvidia-compute-utils-450_450.36.06-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 unable to make backup link of './usr/bin/nvidia-cuda-mps-control' before installing new version: Invalid cross-device link
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Preparing to unpack .../nvidia-utils-450_450.36.06-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nvidia-utils-450 (450.36.06-0ubuntu1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cuda-repo-ubuntu1804-11-0-local/./nvidia-utils-450_450.36.06-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 unable to make backup link of './usr/bin/nvidia-debugdump' before installing new version: Invalid cross-device link
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cuda-repo-ubuntu1804-11-0-local/./nvidia-compute-utils-450_450.36.06-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
 /var/cuda-repo-ubuntu1804-11-0-local/./nvidia-utils-450_450.36.06-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Here we are.. how to fix `unable to make backup link of './usr/bin/nvidia-cuda-mps-control' before installing new version: Invalid cross-device link` ?

Thanks a lot !

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
Release:        18.04
Codename:       bionic
```

Comment: Oh, 313 not fully installed or removed. Make a backup first. `dpkg -l | egrep -v '^ii|rc'`

Comment: What `dpkg -l | egrep -v '^ii|rc'` it supposed to give?

Comment: shows packages in unclean state.

Comment: Do you need CUDA 11, which may actually require the 450 driver?  This is a common problem (Nvidia cuda packages depend upon the too (old,new) Nvidia driver they supply, See the suggested solutions on this site for using the default (440) drivers on CUDA 10.2..

Answer (score 3):

At the time of this writing you need to resolve the conflict manually:

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite /var/cache/apt/archives/libnvidia-compute-450_450.36.06-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```

followed by:

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install
```

Source: https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/problem-with-apt-and-nvidia-440-on-ubuntu-20-04/115281/4