# Failing to upgrade Ubuntu 20.04 LTS to 22.04 LTS on ODROID M1

Tags: apt, package-management

I just bought an ODROID M1 and it included a 16GB eMMC card with Ubuntu 20.04 LTS pre-installed on it. I booted up the machine, and ran the following:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade --yes
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

The upgrade to Ubuntu 22.04 Jammy Jellyfish failed, and the system stayed at 20.04 LTS.

When I try to re-run the upgrade process with `do-release-upgrade`, I am getting the following output:

```
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading.
```

Then when I try to run `apt-get upgrade`, I get the following:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 hplip : Depends: hplip-data (= 3.21.12+dfsg0-1) but 3.20.3+dfsg0-2 is installed
         Depends: libhpmud0 (= 3.21.12+dfsg0-1) but 3.20.3+dfsg0-2 is installed
         Depends: printer-driver-hpcups (= 3.21.12+dfsg0-1) but 3.20.3+dfsg0-2 is installed
 libegl-mesa0 : Depends: libgbm1 (= 22.0.5-0ubuntu0.1) but 21.2.6-0ubuntu0.1~20.04.2 is installed
 libegl1 : Depends: libglvnd0 (= 1.3.2-1~ubuntu0.20.04.2) but 1.4.0-1 is installed
 libgles2 : Depends: libglvnd0 (= 1.3.2-1~ubuntu0.20.04.2) but 1.4.0-1 is installed
 libsane-hpaio : Depends: libhpmud0 (>= 3.21.12+dfsg0) but 3.20.3+dfsg0-2 is installed
 network-manager-gnome : Depends: libayatana-appindicator3-1 (>= 0.4.90) but it is not installed
 python3-brlapi : Depends: libbrlapi0.8 (>= 6.4) but it is not installed
 python3-pil : Depends: libraqm0 (>= 0.7.0) but it is not installed
 python3-uno : Depends: libreoffice-common (>= 1:7.0.0~alpha~) but 1:6.4.7-0ubuntu0.20.04.4 is installed
               Depends: libreoffice-core (= 1:7.3.5-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) but 1:6.4.7-0ubuntu0.20.04.4 is installed or
                        libreoffice-core-nogui (= 1:7.3.5-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) but it is not installed
 rhythmbox-plugins : Depends: librhythmbox-core10 (= 3.4.4-5ubuntu1) but 3.4.4-1ubuntu2 is installed
                     Depends: rhythmbox (= 3.4.4-5ubuntu1) but 3.4.4-1ubuntu2 is installed
                     Depends: gir1.2-rb-3.0 (= 3.4.4-5ubuntu1) but 3.4.4-1ubuntu2 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

When I try to run an `apt --fix-broken install`, I am currently getting the following

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  gir1.2-clutter-1.0 gir1.2-clutter-gst-3.0 gir1.2-cogl-1.0 gir1.2-coglpango-1.0 gir1.2-gtkclutter-1.0 libmanette-0.2-0 libntfs-3g883
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  fonts-opensymbol gir1.2-rb-3.0 hplip-data libayatana-appindicator3-1 libayatana-ido3-0.4-0 libayatana-indicator3-7 libboost-filesystem1.74.0 libboost-iostreams1.74.0 libboost-locale1.74.0 libboost-thread1.74.0 libbrlapi0.8 libegl1 libgbm1 libgles2 libgpgme11 libgpgmepp6 libhpmud0 liborcus-0.17-0 liborcus-parser-0.17-0 libraqm0 libreoffice-base-core libreoffice-calc
  libreoffice-common libreoffice-core libreoffice-draw libreoffice-gnome libreoffice-gtk3 libreoffice-impress libreoffice-math libreoffice-style-tango libreoffice-style-yaru libreoffice-writer librhythmbox-core10 libuno-cppuhelpergcc3-3 libuno-sal3 libxmlsec1 libxmlsec1-nss printer-driver-hpcups rhythmbox rhythmbox-data uno-libs-private ure
Suggested packages:
  libreoffice-base ocl-icd-libopencl1 | mesa-opencl-icd | beignet-opencl-icd gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad gstreamer1.0-libav libreoffice-evolution libreofficekit-data fonts-crosextra-caladea fonts-crosextra-carlito libreoffice-java-common default-jre | java8-runtime | jre hplip-doc gnome-codec-install rhythmbox-plugin-cdrecorder
  rhythmbox-plugin-zeitgeist
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  libappindicator3-1
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libayatana-appindicator3-1 libayatana-ido3-0.4-0 libayatana-indicator3-7 libboost-filesystem1.74.0 libboost-iostreams1.74.0 libboost-locale1.74.0 libboost-thread1.74.0 libbrlapi0.8 liborcus-0.17-0 liborcus-parser-0.17-0 libraqm0 libreoffice-style-yaru
The following packages will be upgraded:
  fonts-opensymbol gir1.2-rb-3.0 hplip-data libegl1 libgbm1 libgles2 libgpgme11 libgpgmepp6 libhpmud0 libreoffice-base-core libreoffice-calc libreoffice-common libreoffice-core libreoffice-draw libreoffice-gnome libreoffice-gtk3 libreoffice-impress libreoffice-math libreoffice-style-tango libreoffice-writer librhythmbox-core10 libuno-cppuhelpergcc3-3 libuno-sal3 libxmlsec1
  libxmlsec1-nss printer-driver-hpcups rhythmbox rhythmbox-data uno-libs-private ure
30 upgraded, 12 newly installed, 1 to remove and 791 not upgraded.
503 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/100 MB of archives.
After this operation, 34.8 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Extracting templates from packages: 100%
(Reading database ... 106980 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libgbm1_22.0.5-0ubuntu0.1_arm64.deb ...
Unpacking libgbm1:arm64 (22.0.5-0ubuntu0.1) over (21.2.6-0ubuntu0.1~20.04.2) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libgbm1_22.0.5-0ubuntu0.1_arm64.deb (--unpack):
 unable to make backup link of './usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libgbm.so.1.0.0' before installing new version: Invalid cross-device link
Preparing to unpack .../libegl1_1.4.0-1_arm64.deb ...
Unpacking libegl1:arm64 (1.4.0-1) over (1.3.2-1~ubuntu0.20.04.2) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libegl1_1.4.0-1_arm64.deb (--unpack):
 unable to make backup link of './usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libEGL.so.1.1.0' before installing new version: Invalid cross-device link
Preparing to unpack .../libgles2_1.4.0-1_arm64.deb ...
Unpacking libgles2:arm64 (1.4.0-1) over (1.3.2-1~ubuntu0.20.04.2) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libgles2_1.4.0-1_arm64.deb (--unpack):
 unable to make backup link of './usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libGLESv2.so.2.1.0' before installing new version: Invalid cross-device link
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libgbm1_22.0.5-0ubuntu0.1_arm64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libegl1_1.4.0-1_arm64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libgles2_1.4.0-1_arm64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

**Question**: How do I fix this "*invalid cross-device link*" error message, so that I can get these packages fixed into a normal state?

Comment: It will be simpler to fresh install Ubuntu 22.04.

Comment: If you *really* want to get your hands dirty and use this as a learning experience, then see https://askubuntu.com/questions/1252188/cuda-install-issue-invalid-cross-device-link for a similar case.

Comment: @user535733 I actually came across that post, and tried running the `dpkg --force-ovewrite` command that was in the answer. Unfortunately, the same cross-device link error appears with that command.